# How to handl this masterpage in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am now creating a website.I v almost done for Login page,register page and change password page.I v created the masterpage which is `masterpage.master`.

After i create a folder Accoumt and put all three pages ( `login,register,changepassword aspx`) into this Account folder.My masterpage is not working `there.Masterpage` cannot load in the folder

If i move those 3 pages outside of the folder...it works well.

Could you give me idea pls?

The master page in these 3 sentences are working at the ouside of the Account Folder.Otherwise it does not work...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChangePassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="Account_ChangePassword" Title="Change Password"%>

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Account_Login" Title="LoginPage" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" Title="Register" %>
```

[image]

Comment: It should work. Can you add more details?

Answer (score 2):

May be a silly answer, but have you tried this?

```
MasterPageFile="../MasterPage.master"
```

assuming that your master page is in the upper level from your pages.

give it a try and let me know.

Comment: i v already tried this one..It still doesn't work ..Sure itis the upper level from my pages

Comment: ok, can you post a screenshot of your project hierarchy as well as the code inside your masterpage file ?